# Adding packages to the VSCode LaTex workshop extension to LaTeX

Tags: latex-workshop

Avid user of latex workshop on VSCode but I'm unsure of how to add packages. The VSCode tex compiler asks for a `.sty` file for the packages that I'm trying to import, but I've got no idea of how to supply this. Perhaps my googling skills are off but I've had zero luck finding information about how to set this up online. Thanks for any help!

Comment: VS Code is only a editor. You should update your TeX Live or MiKTeX.

Comment: If you have an up-to-date TeX Live or MikTeX installation, normal packages listed on CTAN will exist. If you are using some custom style file not included in the TeX distribution, you have to ask for it (from where you get your template).